# Update contents of Arraylist per iteration

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I'm trying to find a way to update the contents of an ArrayList where an element if removed iteratively based on a condition. What I have is an algorithm that uses a user-selected method (via a switch case) to solve the problem in a particular way. However, if no improvement is found after a certain amount of iterations, it randomly selects a different available method (case).

**Goal:**
If a method is selected it should not be available again.

**Code:**

```
        public Solution solve() throws IOException, EclipseException {

        // Account for all the available switch cases
        ArrayList<Integer> selection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int y = 1; y < 12; y++) {
            selection.add(new Integer(1*y));
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> listToKeep = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        // Iterative process with a counter for each iteration that provides 
        // no improvement 

            if (counter == 6) {
                for (Integer num : selection) {
                    if (num != method){
                        listToKeep.add(num);
                        }
                }
                selection.clear();
                selection.addAll(listToKeep);
                System.out.println("Sent for selection " + selection);

                Random rand = new Random(); 
                method = selection.get(rand.nextInt(selection.size()));
                System.out.println("New randomly selected method is: " + method);

                solve(method);
            }
        }   
        return bestSolution;
    }
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
All cases: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] 
Initital method chosen: 1

Sent for selection [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] 
New randomly selected method is: 8

Sent for selection [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
New randomly selected method is: 9

etc.
```

**Issue:**
The for loop keeps referring to the original ArrayList selection containing all numbers (instead of the updated on based on listToKeep) and only removes the last selected case.

**Question:**
How can I assure that the selection ArrayList is correctly updated per iteration?

Any feedback or alternative approaches are much appreciated!

**Solution edit 18-06**

```
        if (!alreadyExecuted){
            selection = IntStream.range(1, 12).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.shuffle(selection);
        }
        alreadyExecuted = true;

        int newMethod = selection.get(selection.size() - 1);
        selection.remove(selection.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing a random element from a list,
it will be simpler and more efficient to shuffle the list,
and always take the last element.

```
List<Integer> selection = IntStream.range(1, 13).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(selection);
```

The last element of this list will be random.
And removing the last element is cheap.
(In case of an `ArrayList` as in your example,
removing an element in the middle requires copying the elements that are after it.)

Comment: Thanks Janos for your very smart alternative. If I understand it correctly: 1) my new method equals the last element of the shuffled list. 2) the last element gets removed thereafter.

Comment: @ArjenPeters that's right, and then either remove the last element, or use an index to track the next element to select.

Comment: @Jonas Roger! I have to play with it a bit I think. With method = selection.get(selection.size() - 1); selection.remove(selection.size() - 1); the list remains the same length.

Comment: @ArjenPeters I don't see how the list can possibly remain the same length after `selection.remove(selection.size() - 1)`. I suspect you're overlooking something.

Comment: @Jonas Yeah I think I've found the issue. I've accepted in the meantime your answer to credit you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Iterator` in case of concurrent modification. Something like

```
List<Integer> selection = new ArrayList<>();

for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = selection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Integer val = iterator.next();
    if (check_for_condition) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a very similar iterator in place before and it worked regarding removing the element if the condition was true but it didn't update the overall content of selection over several iterations as described in my desired outcome. But I will double check it and come back to you.